# Does installing Ubuntu on my Nexus 7 void the warranty?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Are there any steps to return my device to factory defaults with stock android? Will the warranty still be valid if so?

Answer (score 4):

According to Google, as long as Stock Android is running and the bootloader is re-locked, the warranty will still be valid.

To return the device to stock android, please follow the directions on [Installation](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation). To re-lock the bootloader, place the device into fastboot mode, and run

```
sudo fastboot oem lock
```